# How to run Python script with list separated by commas and spaces as argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to run a Python script with an argument as a list. The script needs to grab that parameter and convert it into a list. The list elements in the argument can be separated either by `commas` or by `spaces` or by `comma+space` like this:

```
python test.py 1,2,3,4
python test.py 1 2 3 4
python test.py 1, 2, 3, 4
```

To accommodate the first option, I do the following and it seems to work:

```
>> import sys
>> myList = sys.argv[1]
>> myList = myList.split(",") 
>> myList = [int(i) for i in myList]

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I modify this script to accommodate the other two options?

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list, iterate over it, collect.

Comment: What have you tried for the others?  You appear to have the basic tools well in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over `sys.argv[1:]`, split each part on `,`, collect as `int`:

```
import sys

l = []
for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    for part in a.split(","):
        if part.strip():
            l.append(int(part.strip()))
print(l)
```

The output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

for all inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would require *one* input format for good measure.

As it stands, you have no choice but to handle each case differently, or at least each group of cases. With what you've done so far, you seem to be up to the task. To handle both of the cases with more than one argument, the easy way is to strip away any commas that might or might not be there:

```
args = [arg.strip(',') for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
```

Comment: "you have no choice but to handle each case differently" That is wrong, see the other answers.

Comment: I disagree in that your solution contains the same cases, but rather than stating it as explicit conditionals, it's implicit. Imagine explaining the code to someone: I'm sure you, like me, would describe the outer and inner loops as being there to deal with different input formats.

Comment: I disagree :) Handling cases differently would mean logical branches based on the *complete input*. That's not what I do.

Comment: My point is, in your solution, the work of splitting up the list is done _either_ by the outer loop _or_ the inner loop (unless the user for some perverse reason starts mixing and matching). The input may always go the same route, but that's immaterial to my point: you have two different control structures (loops) to handle two different types of input. For the sake of legibility, I'd much rather have them be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sql_string = [x for x in sys.argv[1].split(',')]

print(sql_string)

# Output:
# python test.py 1,2

# ['1', '2']
```

Comment: This solution does not answer the question. It only addresses the part of the question that the author already knows how to solve, but in a worse way (`split` already returns a list)